# No label found exception on cloud contract testing on the consumer side

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, microservices, spring-cloud-contract

Need your help on cloud contract testing on the spring boot microservice project with rabbitmq.

I have a microservice service that produces messages to a rabbit MQ channel and is listened by another
microservice which listens to it.

Publisher side cloud contract testing is done successfully and it pushes the generated stubs to a repo.

Consumer side test is done written but it fails since it could not able to find the label in the stub .

and the list of labels in the stub is also empty.

I opened the stub.jar and I could find the contract file which is contract_name.groovy.

I could see a contract_name.yaml file generated in the target folder of the producer but it's not available
in the stub.jar which is downloaded on the consumer build.

what format of the contract file does the stubrunner on the consumer side use.
contract_name.groovy or contract_name.yaml.

error message on consumer side testing

```
 IllegalArgumentException No label with name [return_book_for_foo] was found.Here you have the list of dependencies and their labels [Dependency [com.uuuhhh.com.cpp-event:1.0.0-snapshot]:stubs] has labels []]
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and it turned out the cause was improperly setting `stubrunner.stubs-per-consumer: true`. The producer in my case was **not** identifying stubs separately by consumer, so setting this property instead to `false` fixed the empty set of labels.